# How to print two Different Tables using jspdf-autotable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to print these two tables as pdf using jspdf autotable plugin. But the script that I wrote prints only second table. I think the problem lies in writing script. Will someone guide me how to print these two tables using jspdf-autotable.

```
        <button onclick="generate()">Print</button>

<table id="tbl1" border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Marks</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>Johnson</td>
                    <td>UK</td>
                    <td>112</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>Jim</td>
                    <td>US</td>
                    <td>142</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>Johnson</td>
                    <td>UK</td>
                    <td>112</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>Jim</td>
                    <td>US</td>
                    <td>142</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table id="tbl2" border="2">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Julia</td>
                <td>Anderson</td>
                <td>2312144</td>
                <td>Good</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Emma</td>
                <td>Watson</td>
                <td>24564456</td>
                <td>Excellent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jim</td>
                <td>Carry</td>
                <td>5645648</td>
                <td>Seperb</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Harry</td>
                <td>Potter</td>
                <td>544562310</td>
                <td>Ridiculous</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

this is script:

```
<script>
    function generate() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');

        var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tbl1"), true);
        doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {margin: {top: 80}});

        var res2 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tbl2"), true);
        doc.autoTable(res2.columns, res2.data, {margin: {top: 80}});

        doc.save("test.pdf");

    }
</script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.1.0/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second table is most likely printed on top of the first one. You would have to specify the start position of the second table like so:

```
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('tbl1'));
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
var res2 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('tbl2'));
doc.autoTable(res2.columns, res2.data, {
    startY: doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 50
});
```

Comment: when table 2 going to be more than one page can i repeat table one for every page ? -Simon Bengtsson

Answer (score 3):

Example with latest jspdf version

```
var doc = new jsPDF("landscape");
var header = function () {
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setTextColor(40);
                doc.setFontStyle('bold');
                doc.text("Article", 15, 10);
              
};
    doc.autoTable({html:"#table1", didDrawPage: header});

    doc.autoTable({html:"#table2", didDrawPage: header});

    doc.autoTable({html:"#table3", didDrawPage: header});

    doc.autoTable({html:"#table4", didDrawPage: header});

    doc.autoTable({html:"#table5", didDrawPage: header});
    doc.save('myPDF.pdf')
```

Comment: You need to add [jspdf-autotable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable) along with jspdf. Example -  import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import 'jspdf-autotable';

Answer (score 1):

If you use doc.autoTableHtmlToJson does not consider a head and duplicate one row.
That's works for me:

```js
generate(){
    const doc = new jsPDF()

    doc.autoTable({
      theme: 'plain',      
      headStyles: { fontSize: 10 },
      bodyStyles: { fontSize: 8, fontStyle: 'italic' },      

      head:  [['ID', 'Name', 'Country']],
      body: [['1', 'Simon', 'Sweden'], ['2', 'Karl', 'Norway']],          

    });

    doc.autoTable({
      theme: 'plain',      
      headStyles: { fontSize: 10 },
      bodyStyles: { fontSize: 8, fontStyle: 'italic' },      

      head:  [['ID', 'Name', 'Country']],
      body: [['1', 'Simon', 'Swedenddd'], ['2', 'Karl', 'Norway']],          

    });

    // doc.save('table.pdf');  
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); //to check pdf generate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

only add startY to second table

```
 <script>
  function generate() {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');

    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tbl1"), true);
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {margin: {top: 80}});

    var res2 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tbl2"), true);
    doc.autoTable(res2.columns, res2.data, startY: doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 20, {margin: {top: 80}});

    doc.save("test.pdf");
}
</script>
```